# How to obtain this substring result in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, substring

I am facing a problem and I am not finding the best solution to solve it. Imagine I have this string:

> https://www.example.com/examplePhoto/stuffs/10156664251312164/?result=33

What is the best way to obtain the substring **10156664251312164** value? It can have different sizes it could be this:

> https://www.example.com/examplePhoto/stuffs/3323232/?result=33

And I would like to have the **3323232** value. But I am not finding the bests solution to this. Could you help me? I would liek to do in the most dynamic way possible.

**Also everything that is behind 3323232 like stuffs and examplePhoto can be different. Can have another names or another sizes like this:**

> https://www.example.com/exampleVideos/stuffs_videos/3323232/?result=33

Thank you

Comment: Use a Regular Expression (RegEx).
`#https://www.example.com/examplePhoto/stuffs/(\d+)\?result=33#`

Comment: Seems like if it always comes after the string `stuffs/` and before `/?` that it should be easy enough to do with the standard string functions. Or you could use a regex. Have you attempted anything?

Comment: Sorry, everything that is behind those values also change change. Is not always stuffs neither examplePhoto (I edited my post check it again)

Comment: But it always ends at the first slash following the number. Should be easy enough.

Comment: Since your sample strings look strangely like Urls, you might consider using the `System.Uri` class to do the parsing for you.  This will handle cases such as an Url without a querystring.   In particular, look at the property `Uri.Segments`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri.segments?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: simple and quick  string res1 = input.Split('/')[5];

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no need to use regular expressions for this. The `Uri` class was defined specifically to parse URIs. Complete example:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace UrlParserDemo
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var uri = new Uri("https://www.example.com/examplePhoto/stuffs/10156664251312164/?result=33");
            var uri2 = new Uri("https://www.example.com/examplePhoto/stuffs/3323232/?result=33");
            var uri3 = new Uri("https://www.example.com/exampleVideos/stuffs_videos/3323232/?result=33");

            Console.WriteLine($"Example 1: {StripTrailingSlash(uri.Segments.Last())}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Example 2: {StripTrailingSlash(uri2.Segments.Last())}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Example 3: {StripTrailingSlash(uri3.Segments.Last())}");
        }

        private static string StripTrailingSlash(string source)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(source))
            {
                return "";
            }

            if (source.Last() != '/')
            {
                return source;
            }

            return source.Substring(0, source.Length - 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Produces the desired output of:

`Example 1: 10156664251312164
Example 2: 3323232
Example 3: 3323232`

Comment: I would go with this approach; far easier, no need of string/regex handling

Comment: Works for me :D

Answer (score 3):

I think this code should work , if you want get Numeric section :

```
string input = @"https://www.example.com/examplePhoto/stuffs/10156664251312164/?result=33";

var splitedList = input .Split('/');
foreach (var item in splitedList )
{
    int n;
    bool isNumeric = int.TryParse(item , out n);
    if(isNumeric)
         Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After recreating stopper I could understand that replace is much faster.

```
string input = @"https://www.example.com/examplePhoto/stuffs/10156664251312164/?result=33";

            Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

            stopwatch.Start();

                string res1 = input.Split('/')[5];

            stopwatch.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("Time elapsed: {0}", stopwatch.Elapsed);

             stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

            stopwatch.Start();
            string match = Regex.Match(Regex.Match(input, @"[\/][\d]+[\/]").Value, @"[\d]+").Value;
            stopwatch.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("Time elapsed: {0}", stopwatch.Elapsed);
             stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

            stopwatch.Start();
            string res = input.Replace(@"https://www.example.com/examplePhoto/stuffs/", "").Replace(@"/?result=33", "");
            stopwatch.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("Time elapsed: {0}", stopwatch.Elapsed);

Output
    Time elapsed: 00:00:00.0000097
Time elapsed: 00:00:00.0008232
Time elapsed: 00:00:00.0000064
```

Comment: What makes it “best”?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the URL already has the same number of separators '/' then you can perform a Split() on the correct index and use that.

For example,

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var examples = new List<string>
        {
            "https://www.example.com/exampleVideos/stuffs_videos/3323232/?result=33",
            "https://www.example.com/exampleVideos/stuffs_videos/3323232/?result=33"
        };

        int idPositionInUrl = 5;

        foreach (var url in examples)
        {
            var id = url.Split('/')[idPositionInUrl];

            Console.WriteLine("Id: " + id);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string myInput = @"https://www.example.com/examplePhoto/stuffs/10156664251312164/?result=33";
myInput = myInput.Replace(@"https://www.example.com/examplePhoto/stuffs/", "");
var RESULT = myInput.Split('/').ElementAt(0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Below code is dynamic and should work in all scenarios for your particular situation. Let me know if this does not work for you.

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string s = "https://www.example.com/examplePhoto/stuffs/3323232/?result=33";
            var endingstring = "/?result=";
            var strings = s.Substring(0, s.IndexOf(endingstring));
            var len = strings.LastIndexOf("/")+1;
            var thestringineed = strings.Substring(len);            
            Console.WriteLine("The string that i need is " + thestringineed);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This may help you:

```
string myInput = @"https://www.example.com/examplePhoto/stuffs/10156664251312164/?result=33";
myInput = myInput.Replace(@"https://www.example.com/examplePhoto/stuffs/", "");
var RESULT = myInput.Split('/').ElementAt(0);
```